# Image bigger than DIV with vertical centering

Tags: html, css

I was searching for solution for hours but can't find it.

I have div with fixed height and 50% width. And I want to display a picture inside it with 100% width and default aspect ratio but vertically centered

[image: Sample]

Thanks ;)

```
<div class="wrap">
   <img class="img">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I get the idea behind 'downvotes don't require an explanation' but 3 down votes on someone's first question without taking a minute to explain why is just weak. Nerds finally getting to be bullies on the play ground?

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your div and then adjust the margin of the image into the negative. How much depends on the div's fixed height and the image height.

**EDIT**
Consider using CSS and background images if you don't know the image heights. Instead of outputting an image tag, output an inline style on the div.

```
<div class="css-is-good" style="background-image: url(image.jpg);"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.css-is-good {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    /* if you need to stretch it, use background-size: */
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/Cu3G5/

Comment: Thnaks Will, but its not my problem. I have overflow hidden but my problem is i dont know size of picture (useres can upload it). I set `width: 100%; height:auto` to the image. But i want to see the middle of picture, not top :)